# i can't edit my user data

Tags: php, mysqli, dreamweaver

i try to edit/update my data form but when i click on"edit" button it doesn't change anything and i don't know what has exactly happened, the output said

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin\requestform5.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin\requestform5.php on line 24

coding

```
<?php 
include "errorReporting.php";
include "conn.php";
$conn = connect();
$db = connectdb();

$wardID = $_REQUEST["wardID"];
$RequestName = $_REQUEST["RequestName"];
$Department =$_REQUEST["Department"];
$Position =$_REQUEST["Position"];
$Date=$_REQUEST["Date"];

$TypeOfRequest=$_REQUEST["TypeOfRequest"];
$PleaseSpecify=$_REQUEST["PleaseSpecify"];
$DateRequire= $_REQUEST["DateRequire"];
$DateReturn= $_REQUEST["DateReturn"];

mysqli_select_db ($conn,"admin") or die ($conn->error ."\n");
$query = "select*from requestform";
$result= $conn->query($query) or die ($conn->error."\n");
$row_result =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

mysqli_select_db ($conn,"admin") or die ($conn->error."\n");
$mysqli->query( "UPDATE requestform SET RequestName='$RequestName',Department='$Department',Position='$Position',Date='$Date',TypeOfRequest='$TypeOfRequest',PleaseSpecify='$PleaseSpecify',DateRequire='$DateRequire',DateReturn='$DateReturn' where wardID='$wardID'");
$mysqli->affected_rows or die ($conn->error()."\n");


header("Location:requestform3.php");?>
```

Comment: put space between * , select and from  =>  select * from requestform

Comment: @BilalJohn, there is no problem if its in between space...

Comment: @BilalJohn ! I think the problem in line 24 not 20

Comment: problem is with your update query.. this is not how you pass variables to a query.. Your getting above error because update query returns null. 

RequestName=' ".$RequestName." '    use proper quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query is the main problem

```
$query = "select*from requestform";
```

change to this

```
mysqli_select_db ($conn,"admin") or die ($conn->error ."\n");
$query = "select * from requestform";
$result= $conn->query($query) or die ($conn->error."\n");
$row_result =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$conn->query( "UPDATE requestform SET RequestName='$RequestName',Department='$Department',Position='$Position',Date='$Date',TypeOfRequest='$TypeOfRequest',PleaseSpecify='$PleaseSpecify',DateRequire='$DateRequire',DateReturn='$DateReturn' where wardID='$wardID'");
$conn->affected_rows or die ($conn->error()."\n");
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Exprator! I think its not a line 24, which you are referring. The problem with update query.

Comment: i have a problem with this thing  ` $conn->affected_rows or die ($conn->error()."\n");`  the **output** was  `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\misAdmin\requestform5.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\misAdmin\requestform5.php on line 25`

Comment: remove the $conn->error and check and which one is line 25 @Sai

Comment: @Exprator yes it works but i got this output : `Notice: Undefined index: wardID in C:\xampp\htdocs\misAdmin\requestform5.php on line 7`. this is happend from line 7 until line 15

Answer (score 0):

problem is here in 24th number of line

**$mysqli->query**( "UPDATE requestform SET RequestName='$RequestName',Department='$Department',Position='$Position',Date='$Date',TypeOfRequest='$TypeOfRequest',PleaseSpecify='$PleaseSpecify',DateRequire='$DateRequire',DateReturn='$DateReturn' where wardID='$wardID'");
**$mysqli->affected_rows** or die ($conn->error()."\n");

where did this $mysqli come from ?   is this an object ? i cant see this object anywhere.  you do have $conn object.

**just change $mysqli->query  to $conn->query**

Comment: **Output** :  `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\misAdmin\requestform5.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\misAdmin\requestform5.php on line 25`

i've got this..after change "$mysqli" to "$conn"

Comment: You do have to many errors...  now you have probelm in $conn->error . can you share your connection  file. conn.php and other one errorreporting.php ...   replace these lines wherever it is                 or die ($conn->error."\n");  to    ...   or die(mysqli_error($conn));